# Resolving Youtube channel like https://youtube.com/c/xyz

Tags: youtube-api

It is fairly easy to request youtube channel or user info when you have a url like yourtube.com/channel/xyz or youtube.com/user/xyz because you can just strip the username/channelid from the url. However I have problems associating an url like https://youtube.com/c/xyz to any kind of resource.

It doesnt seem to be a user, nor a channel?

Comment: Haven't seen that format. Do you have working examples?

Comment: This one is a good example.

https://www.youtube.com/c/Rsmuk1

Comment: Odd. The actual url for that channel is https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCMi7-BZZX9x8CAhE-5juNyw     Where did you get the /c/Rsmuk1?

Comment: found it on the actual website of the company

https://www.rsmuk.com/

top right corner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTML there is something called the [canonical link element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_link_element). This is an element that you put on a page which is a duplicate of another page and the element points to the canonical or "master" copy of that content.

If you view the source of https://youtube.com/c/Rsmuk1 and search for "canonical" you find the element which points to the primary channel page.

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCMi7-BZZX9x8CAhE-5juNyw">
```

You could therefore retrieve the long url by requesting the page in a language of your choice and then parsing out that element. Here's an example in Python 3 using `BeautifulSoup` and `requests`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

document = requests.get('https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCMi7-BZZX9x8CAhE-5juNyw')

soup = BeautifulSoup(document.content, "lxml")
links = soup.findAll('link', rel='canonical')
for link in links:
    print(link['href'])

# Prints: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCMi7-BZZX9x8CAhE-5juNyw
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay. It turns out it's a [custom url](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2657968?hl=en) you can manually request from YouTube. It has no connection to a userName or channelID.

There also is currently no way to use the API to get info from a custom url, so instead you would need to request the url and look in the meta tags for the actual channelID. Here is a [PHP script](https://gist.github.com/janyksteenbeek/7fd472fb745f9ef96968b0ef467b8fbb) to do just that. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Youtube has changed HTML code and remove link rel="canonical", so solution from Jacob Tomlinson is not working any more.

Now you need to grab ChannelID from any other places in source code, from this one, for example:

```
<meta itemprop="channelId" content="UCMi7-BZZX9x8CAhE-5juNyw">
```

PHP:

```
preg_match_all('#<meta itemprop="channelId" content="([^"]+)"#is', $html, $channel_id);
```